# no provider for BarcodeScanner

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

The code is as follows:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';

    @Component({
        selector: 'page-home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {
        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private translate: TranslateService, private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) {

        }
        //Switch language 
       changelanguage() {
            let browserLang = this.translate.currentLang;
            this.translate.use(browserLang.match(/en/) ? 'zh' : 'en');
        }
        //Scan test
        ScanCode() {
            this.barcodeScanner.scan()
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error);
                });
        }
    }
```

Error Picture:

[image]

Reference：https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/

new questions arose:
According to Suraj recommendations, the prompt "plugin_not_installed"

Error Picture:
[image]
[image]
development environment:
Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to set the scanner as provider in **app.module.ts**

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    BarcodeScanner
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Reference: [Add Plugins to Your App's Module here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/)

UPDATE:
From your package.json it looks like you have installed older `ionic-native - 2.4.1`.Remove it and do:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/core
```

Comment: 按你说的我已经加上了，但是调用方法提示 “plugin_not_installed”

Comment: catch((error) => {
                    alert(error);
                });

Comment: 运行到这里 提示 “plugin_not_installed”

Comment: `$ ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner --save
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner` did you do this?

Comment: It's a good itea test the solutions, this doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with **ionic cli 3.9.2**.

I solved it using `npm i @ionic-native/barcode-scanner@beta --save`.

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx";

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    BarcodeScanner
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue at android device after installing `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner --save` which error message is `plugin_not_installed`. Just added `CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION` variable inside `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner` tag at `config.xml` and working :)

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="^7.0.1">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
</plugin>
```